# Can we use direct OneHotEncoding without LabelEncoding for catagorical data in spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can we use directly OneHotEncoding without LabelEncoding for catagorical data in spyder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Also, it has nothing to do with Spyder, Spyder is just an IDE.
Here's an example.

```
>>> X = [['India', 1], ['USA', 2], ['India', 3]]
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder()
>>> enc.fit(X)
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=None, categories=None,
       dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>, handle_unknown='error',
       n_values=None, sparse=True)
>>> enc.get_feature_names()
array(['x0_India', 'x0_USA', 'x1_1', 'x1_2', 'x1_3'], dtype=object)
```